# Required subdocuments Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have defined the following Mongoose schemas

```
var subSchema = new Schema({
    propertySub: {type: String, required: true}
});

var mainSchema = new Schema({
    mainProperty: {type: String, required: true},
    subs: [subSchema]
});
```

As you may see there is a required property on `subSchema`, and the problem is that I want a `mainSchema` to be required to have at least one `subSchema`, but when I send a

```
{
    "mainProperty" : "Main"
}
```

nothing fails.

I tried something like

```
subs: [{
    type: subSchema,
    required: true
}]
```

But it throws the following:

> TypeError: Undefined type `undefined` at array `subs`

So anyway to do this?, maybe with `validate` I'm new to node and mongoose so an explication will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you will either want to use validate, or you can validate with a presave hook if you want. Here's an example of using validate

```
var mainSchema = new Schema({
    mainProperty: {type: String, required: true},
    subs: {
      type: [subSchema],
      required: true,
      validate: [notEmpty, "Custom error message"]
    }
});

function notEmpty(arr) {
  return arr.length > 0;
}
```